# Paste Values Only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the script below to copy data from one sheet to another. I'm using a manual trigger to perform the task. The problem is that the formats from the copied sheet are being pasted with the values causing the next operation to be pasted below a bunch of empty cells that only contain formats.Trying to keep a clean transfer sheet without gaps. Any help would be appreciated.
Current script:

```
function copyInfo()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");

    // get source range
    var source = copySheet.getRange('A2:L');

    // get destination range
    var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,5,12);

    // copy values to destination range
    source.copyTo(destination);

    // clear source values
    source.clearContent();
}
```

Comment: I've tried both suggestions above and below and I keep losing the formulas from the source page. I cant seem to figure out if it's part of the copy or the clear Contents at the end? Sorry, I'm new to google apps script writing any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the Google Spreadsheet API (I edited your question to add the tag).

According to the documentation, you can specify the type of copy-paste in the `copyTo()` method :

```
source.copyTo(destination, spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
```

Here is [the documentation on copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,CopyPasteType,Boolean)), and here are [all the copy types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type).

Answer (score 0):

`.copyTo` supports [optional parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination):

```
source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly:true});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The copy and paste part is working good, but I'm still losing the formulas from the source page. Basically have one row of formulas in column B. Sorry, I'm new at this....any ideas? thanks again